# zsh illegal hardware instruction c

Tags: c, malloc, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I'm doing an exercise for the multiple execution of commands passed by the cmd arguments.

The description of the exercise is: "*The program must read the file line by line, executing the command specified in the command line once for each line, replacing at each occurrence of '@' in the command line, the contents of the current line of the file.*"

But as soon as I execute `./file_exec esempio.txt cat @` the cli shows me this error `zsh illegal hardware instruction`.

I put here the various file that I've create:

**main.c**

```
#include "file_exec.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if(argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr,
      "Specificare il file di testo e il comando da eseguire.\n");
    return 1;
  }

  char *filename = argv[1];
  int cmdargc = argc - 2;
  char **opz = argv + 2;
  char *cmd = argv[2];
  char *line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * BUZZ_SIZE);
  int statusLine = 0;
  FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

  if(file == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: Impossibile aprire %s: %s\n",
    argv[0], argv[1], strerror(errno));
    return 2;
  }
  int size = 1024;
  do{
    statusLine = fileReadLine(line, file, size); // leggo la singola linea
    if(statusLine == 2){
      size += 1024;
    }
    if(strlen(line) != 0){
      int ris = executeLine(cmdargc, cmd, opz);

      if(ris == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Impossibile eseguire il comando: %s\n", cmd);
        return -1;
      }
    }

  }while(statusLine != -1);

  fclose(file);
  return 0;

}
```

**file_exec.c**

```
#include "file_exec.h"

int fileReadLine(char *line, FILE *file, int size){

  if(!feof(file) && (int)strlen(line) < size){
    fgets(line, size, file);
  }else if((int)strlen(line) == size){
    line = realloc(line, size*2);
    return 2;
  }else{
    free(line);
    return -1;
  }

  return 1;
}

int executeLine(int nOpz, char *cmd, char **opz){

  char *pathCmd = strcat("/bin/",cmd);
  pid_t pidSon = fork();
  opz = addArguments(nOpz, cmd, opz);

  switch(pidSon) {
    case -1:
      perror("fork() failed");
      free(opz);
      return 1;

    case 0:
      printf("Esecuzione di ls...\n");
      execl(pathCmd, cmd, opz, NULL);
      perror("exec failed");
      free(opz);
      return 1;

    default:
      wait(NULL);
      printf("%s completed\n",cmd);
  }
  free(opz);
  return 0;
}

char **addArguments(int cmdargc, char *line, char **cmdargv){
  char **newArgs = (char **)malloc((cmdargc + 1) * sizeof(char *));

  for(int i = 0; i < cmdargc; i++){
    if(strcmp(cmdargv[i], "@") == 0){
      newArgs[i] = line;
    }else{
      newArgs[i] = cmdargv[i];
    }
  }

  newArgs[cmdargc] = NULL;

  return newArgs;
}
```

**file_exec.h**

```
#ifndef FILEEX_H__
#define FILEEX_H__
#define BUZZ_SIZE 1024

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int fileReadLine(char *, FILE *, int);
int executeLine(int, char *, char **);
char **addArguments(int, char *, char **);


#endif
```

**esempio.txt**

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

**file1.txt**

```
Hello
```

**file2.txt**

```
I'm
```

**file3.txt**

```
italian
```

**Makefile**

```
file_exec: file_exec.o main.o
    gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c99 file_exec.o main.o -o file_exec
file_exec.o: file_exec.h file_exec.c
    gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c99 -c file_exec.c
main.o: file_exec.h main.c
    gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c99 -c main.c
clean:
    rm -f *.o main
```

(I'm on an Intel Mac)

The program should show this output from this command `./file_exec esempio.txt cat @`:

```
Hello
I'm
italian
```

I've just tried to put some debugging printf after the first if statement on the main.c but it was ignored and not executed.

Comment: At a glance: The `NULL` sentinel argument to `execl` should be cast to a `(char *)`, i.e., `execl(pathCmd, cmd, opz, (char *) NULL);`.

Comment: You tell fileReadLine that the read buffer has length 1024, but in reality, you allocate a buffer of size BUZZ_SIZE. If you change BUZZ_SIZE to something which is smaller than 1024, this would break your code. Also, I wonder why this question is tagged _zsh_. There is nothing in your code which would involve zsh, except that the calling shell (zsh) reports the error; but if you have an illegal HW instruction, **any** shell would report this, so it does not matter which shell you are invoking it from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `strcat` the wrong way

`char *pathCmd = strcat("/bin/",cmd);`

is adding cmd to the end of string (constant array of char) `"/bin"`. And then is returning this array. To be more accurate, what it does, is going at the address `"/bin"` - yes, that is an address - iterates 1 by 1 this address until it finds the terminal 0, that is the end of the string. And copy the content of address `cmd` there. And obviously, you can't do that. Not from a language point of view. Both `"/bin"` and `cmd` are pointers to char, as wanted. And the fact that `"/bin"` is a constant array of chars is not really a problem neither, since `strcat` doesn't change it: it only changes its content. But that string `"/bin"` is stored in an area of memory that your program is not supposed to try to write to. Which it does, when it tries to copy `cmd` after the second `/` of `/bin/`. Hence an execution error.

You need to allocate memory for `pathCmd` and concatenate there

```c
char pathCmd[1024];
strcpy(pathCmd, "/bin/");
strcat(pathCmd, cmd);
```

Well, in reality, you should not do that neither. It is insecure (if cmd overflow the 1024 bytes I allocated here). So you should rather use `strncat`

```c
char pathCmd[1024];
strcpy(pathCmd, "/bin/");
strncat(pathCmd, cmd, 1024-5); // 5 bytes already used by "/bin/"
```

Alternatively, you can use snprintf

```c
char pathCmd[1024];
snprintf(pathCmd, 1024, "/bin/%s", cmd);
```

(it is 1 less line of code, and you don't need to compute the 1024-5 limit, since the limit is for the whole target)

Note that this has nothing to do with `zsh`. `zsh` is just the one complaining because you probably call this in a zsh script.

Comment: Thank you really much @chrslg ! Now it works and the error was really silly